# capture decrypted https content in android by modify the JRE or .so library

Tags: java, android, security, networking, ssl

I want to see the https content send by a app in android .

I think i can modify the `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` class to dump the content or 
if the android use `openssl` as the backend,then i can to modify the `openssl` library.

I just wonder is that possible?

If I want to modify the `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` class ,what should i do?
I think i should do as follows:
1. download the src
2. edit by my need
3. replace the original

But where is the original `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` class?

After some search on OpenSSL,I decide to modify it first because I kown c better than java

Comment: SSL is meant to be secure and not traced back to actual data. Do you want to see what an other app sends, or your own app?

Comment: Everything is possible on rooted phone, it's just a question of the amount of efforts needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out `libcore`. Modify `luni/src/main/java/org/apache/harmony/luni/internal/net/www/protocol/https/HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java` to suit your needs and build `libcore`, replace it on your device, and you should be good to go.

You need root, I suspect you have Cyanogenmod installed on your device. Here's a quick tutorial how to build it (after you have modified libcore):

http://nilvec.com/building-cyanogen-from-source/

It might be a bit outdated, it was written 2 years ago. The Cyanogenmod wiki also has short tutorials on how to build the OS.